# How to simplify very small number to 0 in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am doing some matrix computation with sympy 0.7.6 in python 2.7.10. For example,

```
M = 
[cos(q1), -6.12323399573677e-17*sin(q1),         -1.0*sin(q1), 150*sin(q1)]
[sin(q1),  6.12323399573677e-17*cos(q1),          1.0*cos(q1), 150*sin(q1)]
[      0,                          -1.0, 6.12323399573677e-17,         445]
[      0,                             0,                    0,           1]
```

Then I apply `simplify` to `M` and it results in:

```
M = 
[cos(q1),    0,         -1.0*sin(q1), 150*sin(q1)]
[sin(q1),    0,          1.0*cos(q1), 150*sin(q1)]
[      0, -1.0, 6.12323399573677e-17,         445]
[      0,    0,                    0,           1]
```

It's clear that `-6.12323399573677e-17*sin(q1)` is simplified to `0` but  `6.12323399573677e-17` is not. Is it possible to simplify the pure number item with `simplify`?

Comment: Do you have the whole scipy stack or just sympy?

Comment: I have scipy 0.13.0b1

Comment: Note that expressions like `-6.12323399573677e-17*sin(q1)` are not simplified to `0` in the current version of SymPy anymore (which is how I would want it to behave).

Answer (score 4):

Sympy’s `nsimplify` function with the `rational=True` argument converts floats within an expression to rational numbers (within a given tolerance). Something like `6.12323399573677e-17` will be converted to 0 if below the threshold. So, in your case:

```
from sympy import Symbol, Matrix, sin, cos, nsimplify

q1 = Symbol("q1")
M = Matrix([
        [cos(q1), -6.12323e-17*sin(q1),  1.0*sin(q1), 150*sin(q1)],
        [sin(q1),  6.12323e-17*cos(q1),  1.0*cos(q1), 150*sin(q1)],
        [      0,                 -1.0, 6.123233e-17,         445],
        [      0,                    0,            0,           1],
    ])

nsimplify(M,tolerance=1e-10,rational=True)
# Matrix([
# [cos(q1),  0, -sin(q1), 150*sin(q1)],
# [sin(q1),  0,  cos(q1), 150*sin(q1)],
# [      0, -1,        0,         445],
# [      0,  0,        0,           1]])
```

Note how this also converted `-1.0` to `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Matrix (sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix), including one with sybolic elements, the conversion can be done with the following function:

```
def round2zero(m, e):
    for i in range(m.shape[0]):
        for j in range(m.shape[1]):
            if (isinstance(m[i,j], Float) and m[i,j] < e):
                m[i,j] = 0
```

For example:

```
from sympy import *

e = .0000001 # change according to your definition of small
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
mlist = [[0.0, 1.0*cos(z)], [x*y, 1.05000000000000], [0,     6.12323399573677e-17]]
m = Matrix(mlist)
m
Out[4]: 
Matrix([
[0.0,           1.0*cos(z)],
[x*y,                 1.05],
[  0, 6.12323399573677e-17]])

round2zero(m,e)
m
Matrix([
[  0, 1.0*cos(z)],
[x*y,       1.05],
[  0,          0]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. However, np.abs() can not be applied to symbolic terms in sympy matrix. It returns TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Abs(cos(q1)) < 0.0001. I thought there would be simply solution to this question but it appears not.  I have to go through each item and check whether it is numerical.

Answer (score 0):

Some fuzzing can help detect more values that can be set to zero:

```
import sympy
import random


def fuzz_simplify(matrix, min=-1.0, max=1.0, iterations=1000, tolerance=0.005):
    m = sympy.Matrix(matrix)
    free_sym = range(len(J.free_symbols))
    f = sympy.lambdify(m.free_symbols,m)

    sum = f(*[0 for i in free_sym])

    for i in range(0, iterations):
        rand_params = [random.uniform(min,max) for i in free_sym]
        sum += f(*rand_params)

    for i in range(0, J.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, J.shape[1]):
            if sum[i,j] < tolerance:
                m[i,j] *= 0

    return m
```